# I am using Selenium and Python to scrape data from the web. Why does my .find_elements always return an empty list?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm new to working with Selenium and XPaths, so please don't get mad if I've made a really simple mistake here.

I'm trying to scrape the amount of stars of a repository on GitHub from pages such as this: https://github.com/orgs/PowerShell/repositories. I'm  using Selenium with Python and have set up a driver that is working (it works with other XPaths).

This is how the elements containing the amount of stars rougly look like:
[elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNssf.png). If you need further information about the page structure, visit the example above.

In order to get a list of the `span` tags which contain the amounts of stars, I tried different XPaths.

Here are some examples of what I've tried:

1)

```
links = driver.find_elements(
    "xpath", "//a[.//svg[contains(@class, 'octicon octicon-star')]]")
```

2. 

```
links = driver.find_elements(
    "xpath", "//a[.//svg[class='octicon octicon-star']]")
```

3. 

```
links = driver.find_elements(
    "xpath", "//a[.//svg[.//path[d='M8 .25a.75.75 0 01.673.418l1.882 3.815 4.21.612a.75.75 0 01.416 1.279l-3.046 2.97.719 4.192a.75.75 0 01-1.088.791L8 12.347l-3.766 1.98a.75.75 0 01-1.088-.79l.72-4.194L.818 6.374a.75.75 0 01.416-1.28l4.21-.611L7.327.668A.75.75 0 018 .25zm0 2.445L6.615 5.5a.75.75 0 01-.564.41l-3.097.45 2.24 2.184a.75.75 0 01.216.664l-.528 3.084 2.769-1.456a.75.75 0 01.698 0l2.77 1.456-.53-3.084a.75.75 0 01.216-.664l2.24-2.183-3.096-.45a.75.75 0 01-.564-.41L8 2.694v.001z']]]")
```

I know there is also a GitHub Api, but I don't want to use it in this example.

There's technically also the issue, that if a repo has zero stars, there will be no `a` tag, but a `span` tag. However, on the example page above, it should still return *some* links. And as long as I don't get to all of the ones with an `a` tag, I won't get to the ones inside a `span` tag anyways. I should be able to solve this pretty easily by introducing a new case or using `parent`. However, if someone also could provide a code example for that, I'd really appreciate it.

Links always ends up being an empty list.

Comment: `//a[.//svg[class='octicon octicon-star']]` Do nested attributes like this really work?  I've never seen this.

Comment: It did here: https://youtu.be/SPM1tm2ZdK4?t=640

Comment: Well, I would like to find out why what I was trying to do didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple elements, driver.find_elements() needs xpath which appears several times in the page. It looks that xpath of the stars in each repository is different. How about By.CSS_SELECTOR instead of Xpath to get elements?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


user = "PowerShell"
url = f"https://github.com/orgs/{user}/repositories"

driver.get(url)

repositories_li = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[class='Box-row']")

for repo in repositories_li:
    
    title = repo.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[itemprop='name codeRepository']").text

    try:
        star = repo.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,f"[href='/{user}/{title}/stargazers']").text
    
    except NoSuchElementException:
        star = repo.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,f"[class='mr-3 color-fg-muted']").text

    print(title,star)

--------------
PowerShell-Docker 324
PowerShell 37,068
PowerShellGet 340
.
.
.
```

If repository has no star and selenium can't find element, it raises NoSuchElementException. Then,"[class='mr-3 color-fg-muted']" appears and the text is 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly fine. Still curious though why my way didn't work.

Comment: Did you get stars?  Xpath can copy from your browser's validation tool. The youtube video was not copied which you referenced. I think that you couldn't find element because of xpath.

Comment: Besides, selenium doc says that the first argument of fint_element is written By.XPATH,ID,TAG_NAME etc.(https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#all-matching-elements) Your code is passed "xpath".

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the more common way. Using ("xpath", ...") still worked though in other cases.

Yeah, something must have been wrong with my xpath. No idea what though.

Comment: I think that find_element() was passed wrong xpath. I tried seach that your xpath by chrome developper tool, but element wasn't hitted.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I just need to find out why, cause to my knowledge, it should have worked.